# rake Don't know how to build task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I have rake task called

> myapi.rake

The contents of the file is something like this:

```
require 'active_record'
namespace :myapi do
  task :populate_terminals do
    #My model and it's method
    Terminnal.populate
  end
end
```

When I run bundle exec rake myapi, I get the following error:

> Don't know how to build task myapi

when I do a bundle exec rake myapi --trace, This is what I get

> /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in
>   `[]'
>   ebâ/home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:148:in`
>   invoke_task'
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   each'
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block in top_level'
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`
>   run_with_threads'
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in
>   `top_level'
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`
>   block in run' 
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`
>   run'
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/rake:23:in`load' $
>   /home/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/rake:23:in `'

I would appreciate any help in debugging this. there are some similar questions in stackoverflow, but none of the recommended solution seems to work.

Is the above error misleading, and the problem lies somehwere in my code?

Comment: `bundle exec rake myapi:populate_terminals` - you aren't specify task name (only namespace).

Comment: thanks maxd. I am embarassed!